# Weird behaviour of stderr

Tags: c++, c, stdout, stderr

I have this code in my program

```
while(1){
  // some code here

 fprintf(stdout,"Output Log");
 fprintf(stderr,"Error Log");


 //some code here
      }
```

It prints only "Error Log". It looked like I was missing to flush between two fprintf. Hence I appended "\n" to String "Output log". Worked fine. But cannot understand this weird behavior when  I just swapped two fprintf

```
while(1){
  // some code here
 fprintf(stderr,"Error Log\n");
 fprintf(stdout,"Output Log");    

 //some code here
      }
```

Inspite of using "\n" it only prints "Error log".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your mistake is assuming that a newline "between" the two messages is what's causing both to appear. It's actually the newline *at the end* of the output to `stdout` which is causing the message to `stdout` to appear (the message to `stderr` is always visible because `stderr` is unbuffered).

In any case, relying on newlines to flush the buffer is unreliable unless you manually set line-buffered mode on `stdout`; line-buffered is only the default when `stdout` is a terminal. If you don't want to force line-buffered or unbuffered mode, then you **must** use `fflush`  to get reliable interleaving of output to `stdout` and `stderr`.

Answer (score 1):

`stderr` is special.  It is never fully buffered at application start like `stdout` may be.  It is implementation dependent as to whether or not it is line buffered, and it may not buffered at all (as it seems here).

It makes no difference if they are tethered to the same output device.  This makes sense when you think about it; you probably want your errors to be flushed as quickly as is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

It appears `stdout` is buffered and `stderr` is not. Since the program never ends, the buffer is never flushed.